# Find how much customer has spent in total

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find which top 10 customers have spent most money in the store.
Amount is money spent on 1 purchase. I need to add up all purchases for each customer and put them in descending order.

```
SELECT amount, name
FROM `payment`, `customer_list`
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I would like to know how to add up the amount for each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sum( ), goup by and inner join .. in the sample the relation between customer is c.id= =p.customer_id   you should adopt  to your real column names

```
SELECT sum(p.amount) tot, c.name
FROM `payment` as p
inner join `customer_list` on c.id= =p.customer_id
group by c.name
ORDER BY tot  DESC
LIMIT 10;
```